# When is the appropriate time to invite more people to join this beta?

Tags: discussion

I know that we are in private beta and not yet "open" to the public. However, I believe newcomers can still join now if sent an invitation or by committing first on Area51.

Since activity levels are presumably an important aspect of ensuring we move on to public beta, should we:

1. Invite more people to participate now including those who were not around for the commitment stage?
2. Keep quiet about the site and focus on creating high quality content instead of increasing activity at this time?

How is Monero doing so far? Are we on pace to graduate to public beta in 3 weeks or so? I can see stats for other sites in beta but they include all data, not just data for the first 2-3 days to compare to where we are now.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think maintaining quality content should be top priority so that is visible when open beta begins.

If we can invite more people now without sacrificing the quality of content I see no problem in doing so.

Hopefully someone knowledgeable can share an opinion about our progress so far in comparison with other sites that did and did not reach public beta.

Answer (score 3):

I asked this on another meta thread already, before seeing this one. So far this whole stackexchange thing has been a Monero community effort imo. But since the scope of this stackexchange includes all cryptonote clones/forks, should we engage the other cryptonote communites? I realize the problem with some of the other devs and their history, otoh they have knowledge on the protocol.

Comment: This post is related by topic, but it seems to me that it is less of an answer but rather a new question. Perhaps it should be instead moved to its own topic.